# Show READY items from org header in agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a situation where I have a lot of similar tasks under a header like so:

```
* Header 
** READY Task 1
** NREADY Task 2
** READY Task 3
** READY Task 4
** NREADY Task 5
```

and so on. What I would like is to have the next READY task (the highest READY task under Header) appear in my agenda every other day or so. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your example, is the "highest READY task" Task 1 or Task 4?

Comment: @Nick - Task 1, though if it's easier to do Task 4 as the "highest", then that could work as well.